# ImportError: cannot import name 'load_strategy'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth

I am setting up a django rest api and need to integrate social login feature.I followed the following link

[Social Auth with Django REST Framework](https://yeti.co/blog/social-auth-with-django-rest-framework/?source=post_page---------------------------)

After setting up when  try to run server getting following error

> from social.apps.django_app import load_strategy
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'load_strategy'

Is there any package i missed? i cant figure out the error.

Comment: Got some code you can share?

Answer (score 0):

From the link you have shared I would recommend not using the tutorial on this website. Part of the issue being the packages and project layout defined are from packages now deprecated.

> **Deprecation notice - 2016-12-03**
>
> As for Dec 03 2016, this library is now deprecated, the codebase was split and migrated into the python-social-auth organization, where a more organized development process is expected to take place.
>
> Details about moving towards the new setup is documented in the migrating to social document.

You will more than likely have incompatibility issues especially if you are using a newer django version.

Instead, I would recommend you take a [look at the new docs](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io). With the [installation page](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html) stating all the new library version to install and use.

Comment: Sorry if it's not the answer you wanted to hear. As a bit of advice for future you, its always worth checking the status of a project on Pypi or github before using it. Just because a package is being used in a tutorial does not mean its the best solution.